# Hyper V- How to access drive on host in guest by drive letter

Tags: hyper-v

I moved my old notebook via Disk2vhd to a virtual Disk. The old Notebook has a c: (System) and a d: (Data) Disk. In Disk2vhd I only select c: Drive.
On the new Notebook, is the same Disk-Layout. I directly copy the old Data-d: to d: on the new Notebook. Then I generate a new virtual machine on the new notebook using the VHD created from c:.

I then want to access the hosts d: in the VM directly. As I learned the hard way, d: could not be a net-share because a lot of programs on (virtual) c: shows errors or don't start if hosts d: is connected as net-share (assigned letter d:).

Another way I  tried is to use "enhanced session". The content of host d: drive is visible/usable in the VMs Explorer below Desktop. It seems not to be possible, to assign a drive letter (d:) to it, so the programs still can't access d:.

Is there a way to give the link in the Explorer the drive letter d: or an other way to use d: directly (not as physical disk, because the host also accesses d:)?

Answer (score 0):

run vmconnect.exe , select options and add local drive. later you can then map a drive letter to it.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

You can convert your "D" with other converter to a sepearate vhd(x) file. Here are the article with V2V converters overview - http://www.vmwareblog.org/v2v-converters-overview/

Comment: Thank you, for answering. I read the articel, but I don't understand, what it will help in my case? I want to access  phsical d: drive from the physical machine and from the virtual machine just as d:. Without any net-shares....